# reuse the result of a select expression in the "GROUP BY" clause?

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In MySQL, I can have a query like this:

```
select  
    cast(from_unixtime(t.time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00') as datetime) as timeHour
    , ... 
from
    some_table t 
group by
    timeHour, ...
order by
    timeHour, ...
```

where `timeHour` in the `GROUP BY` is the result of a select expression.

But I just tried a query similar to that in `Sqark SQL`, and I got an error of

```
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
cannot resolve '`timeHour`' given input columns: ...
```

My query for `Spark SQL` was this:

```
select  
      cast(t.unixTime as timestamp) as timeHour
    , ...
from
    another_table as t
group by
    timeHour, ...
order by
    timeHour, ...
```

Is this construct possible in `Spark SQL`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this construct possible in Spark SQL?

**Yes, It is**. You can make it works in Spark SQL in 2 ways to use new column in `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses

**Approach 1 using sub query :**

```
SELECT timeHour, someThing FROM (SELECT  
      from_unixtime((starttime/1000)) AS timeHour
    , sum(...)                          AS someThing
    , starttime
FROM
    some_table) 
WHERE
    starttime >= 1000*unix_timestamp('2017-09-16 00:00:00')
      AND starttime <= 1000*unix_timestamp('2017-09-16 04:00:00')
GROUP BY
    timeHour
ORDER BY
    timeHour
LIMIT 10;
```

**Approach 2 using WITH // elegant way :**

```
-- create alias 
WITH table_aliase AS(SELECT  
      from_unixtime((starttime/1000)) AS timeHour
    , sum(...)                          AS someThing
    , starttime
FROM
    some_table)

-- use the same alias as table
SELECT timeHour, someThing FROM table_aliase
WHERE
    starttime >= 1000*unix_timestamp('2017-09-16 00:00:00')
      AND starttime <= 1000*unix_timestamp('2017-09-16 04:00:00')
GROUP BY
    timeHour
ORDER BY
    timeHour
LIMIT 10;
```

**Alternative using Spark DataFrame(wo SQL) API with Scala :**

```
// This code may need additional import to work well

val df = .... //load the actual table as df

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn("timeHour", from_unixtime($"starttime"/1000))
  .groupBy($"timeHour")
  .agg(sum("...").as("someThing"))
  .orderBy($"timeHour")
  .show()

//another way - as per eliasah comment
df.groupBy(from_unixtime($"starttime"/1000).as("timeHour"))
  .agg(sum("...").as("someThing"))
  .orderBy($"timeHour")
  .show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But to me it seems it is easier to just repeat the function of the select expression (in this case `from_unixtime((t.starttime/1000))`) in the GROUP BY and ORDER BY.  (See my answer below).  Would you agree?  Note also that if the original query has conditions in a WHERE clause, then I think it is better to put the WHERE clause into the sub-query rather than keep it in the outer query.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hi -- I try to be objective when judging the answers. I think it is easier to just repeat the function in the GROUP BY clause, as described in my own answer.  But I am open to suggestions that can convince me otherwise.  I plan to accept my own answer (admittedly it has not received as many up votes as this answer).  But I think I would give you guys a shout before doing so (in 12 hours from now).  Thanks for your help!

Comment: 1) I am not sure how many times that expression evaluates when you add the same expression in `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` and `SELECT`. But using `WITH` clause/inner query **it's once**. 2) As the expression is simple we can place the same in multiple places, what if it's complicated/resource intensive or/and same table needs to be self joined? in such scenarios, you may need to rethink of it 3) Regarding accepting answer - I answered just to add the another approach of solution, it's up to OP sole decision to accept any answer.

Comment: I agree.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to provide answer myself here ...

It seems to me that we have to rewrite the query and repeat the computation of the select expression in the GROUP BY clause.  For example:

```
select  
      from_unixtime((t.starttime/1000)) as timeHour
    , sum(...)                          as someThing
from
    some_table as t
where
    t.starttime>=1000*unix_timestamp('2017-09-16 00:00:00')
      and t.starttime<=1000*unix_timestamp('2017-09-16 04:00:00')
group by
    from_unixtime((t.starttime/1000))
order by
    from_unixtime((t.starttime/1000))
limit 10;
```