# SparkSQL now allows reusing result of a select expression in GROUP BY and ORDER BY?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

About six months ago (in September 2017), I posted a question asking whether or not `SparkSQL` would allow the reusing of result of a select expression in GROUP BY and ORDER BY.  And the answer was no.  And people are force to use different ways of workarounds, such as writing a subquery or repeat the expression in the GROUP BY (see the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46395333/reuse-the-result-of-a-select-expression-in-the-group-by-clause))

But I just tried again the queries.  Perhaps we have upgraded to use a newer version of SparkSQL.  I noticed that `SparkSQL` now actually allows the reuse.

*Updated with new query examples and a new observation*

Here is an example.  The query (new way) is now allowed:

```
select 
  count(*) cnt,
  date(from_unixtime(t.starttime/1000)) as timeDate  
from someTable as t
group by 
  timeDate
order by 
  timeDate desc
/* Okay */
```

Can we still use the old way?  Based on my experimentation, the answer is 
yes and no.  I don't know if there a bug or it is the intention.

This query was allowed:

```
select 
  count(*) cnt,
  date(from_unixtime(t.starttime/1000)) as timeDate  
from someTable as t
group by 
  date(from_unixtime(t.starttime/1000))
order by 
  date(from_unixtime(t.starttime/1000)) desc
/* Okay */
```

But the following query would triggered an exception:

```
select 
  count(*) cnt,
  cast(date(from_unixtime(t.starttime/1000)) as date) as timeDate  
from someTable as t
group by 
  date(from_unixtime(t.starttime/1000))
order by 
  starttime desc  
/* Error: AnalysisException */
```

Error:

```
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: \
cannot resolve '`starttime`' given input columns: \
[cnt, timeDate]; line 7 pos 9;
```

**See more failure/success cases below**

I understand that in the above example, the `cast(... as date)` is redundant, but here I am just trying to explore what the syntax allows.  If we used the new way (reusing result of select expression), there was no problem.

```
select 
  count(*) cnt,
  cast(date(from_unixtime(t.starttime/1000)) as date) as timeDate  
from someTable as t
group by 
  timeDate
order by 
  timeDate desc
/* Okay */
```

I do like the new way but want to make sure that I have observed correctly.  Can someone confirm it?

I forgot what were the versions six months ago, but here are the current software version:

Our software versions:

- HDFS: 2.7.3
- Hive: 1.2.1
- HBase: 1.1.2
- Spark: 2.0.2
- YARN: 2.7.3
- Spark Thrift Server: 2.2.0
- SQuirreL SQL Client: 3.8.0

**Appendix: More failure/success examples**

It seems that the ORDER BY must match the GROUP BY somehow, or 
an Exception will be thrown.

```
select 
  count(*) cnt,
  date(from_unixtime(t.starttime/1000)) as timeDate  
from someTable as t
group by 
  date(from_unixtime(t.starttime/1000))
order by 
  t.starttime desc 
/* Error: AnalysisException */  

select 
  count(*) cnt,
  cast(date(from_unixtime(t.starttime/1000)) as date) as timeDate  
from someTable as t
group by 
  cast(date(from_unixtime(t.starttime/1000)) as date)
order by 
  cast(date(from_unixtime(t.starttime/1000)) as date) desc   
/* Okay */
```

Comment: I don't use Apache Spark (yet?), so I should probably just keep quiet, but it seems to me that what you want to say is `group by cast(date(from_unixtime(t.starttime/1000)) as date)`.

Comment: @500 - Thanks for pointing that out.  I realized that I had some redundancy in the code, and I just updated my question with new query examples and added a new observation